# How to fix java.lang.NullPointerException: null in Bukkit plugin?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Can't understand how to fix that error, it's unreal to me (can't find where's void in my code):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at survival.MainClass.onEnable(MainClass.java:16) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:403) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:381) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:330) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:422) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:383) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:338) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:272) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:545) [spigot.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_161]
```

16 line is:

```
getCommand(commands.cmd3).setExecutor(commands);
```

Commands class:

```
public class Commands extends CommandExecute implements CommandExecutor, Listener {

public String cmd1 = "fly";
public String cmd2 = "feed";
public String cmd3 = "heal";

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if (sender instanceof Player) {
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cmd3)) {
            Player p = (Player) sender;
            if (p.getHealth() < 20) {
                p.setHealth(20);
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Healed succesfuly!");
                return true;
            } else {
                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You are already healed!");
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    } else {
        sender.sendMessage("Only for Players!");
        return true;
    }

  }

}
```

MainClass:

```
public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{
private Commands commands = new Commands();

public void onEnable() {
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MainHandler(), this);
    getCommand(commands.cmd1).setExecutor(commands);
    getCommand(commands.cmd2).setExecutor(commands);
    getCommand(commands.cmd3).setExecutor(commands);
  }
}
```

Have cmd1 and cmd2 before that and they're working fine, problem with only cmd3 command.

in plugin.yml:

```
name: Survival
main: survival.MainClass
version: 1.1
commands:
  fly:
    description: Toggle flight mode
    usage: /fly
  feed:
    description: Feeds player
    usage: /feed
  heal:
    description: Heals player
    usage: /heal
```

Tried all answers on stackoverflow, but nothing helped me

Comment: Well, obviously this happens at some line in `MainClass.java`. Hard to tell which is line 16, but it probably is in `onEnable()`. Have you already tried to find out what `getServer()` and `getServer().getPluginManager()` return? And, if that succeeds, check `getCommand(commands.cmd1)` etc.?

Comment: You need to add all commands to your `plugin.yml`, not just the `heal` command!

Comment: What is on line 16 in `MainClass.java`

Comment: @Rockey 16 line is: 
    getCommand(commands.cmd3).setExecutor(commands);

Comment: Check if `getCommand(commands.cmd3)` returns `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally did it!

I changed

```
private Commands commands = new Commands();
```

to

```
private Commands commands;
```

and set value for *commands* variable after *onEnable()* and it's looking now:

```
public void onEnable() {
    commands = new Commands();
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new MainHandler(), this);
    getCommand(commands.cmd1).setExecutor(commands);
    getCommand(commands.cmd2).setExecutor(commands);
    getCommand(commands.cmd3).setExecutor(commands);
```